# How to host the main domain and subdomains at 2 different hosting sites from godaddy?

Tags: wordpress, heroku, subdomain, hosting, godaddy-api

I have bought the domain from godaddy.
And I have designed the UI which is the main site hosted at say webflow or wordpress.

Now I want to host the dashboard of the main site to the subdomain of this main site from heroku.

How to achieve that?

**Domain bought:**  goDaddy

**main site:** abcd.com

**sub domain:** dashboard.abcd.com

**main site hosted at:** wordpress

**sub domain hosted at:** abcd.herokuapp.com

Now I want to change the subdomain `abcd.herokuapp.com` to `dashboard.abcd.com`

I tried creating an 'A' record at goDaddy DNS settings for dashboard.abcd.com but it wants me to enter an IP address of heroku but when I created a DNS Zone in Heroku for dashboard.abcd.com, it doesn't seem to provide an IP address. It only provides the DNS Target value.

I laso tried to put the abcd.herokuapp.com in Goddaddy dns settings in Points To field but it doen't accpets it. It requires an IP address.

Answer (score -1):

Heroku uses dynamic IP address for the dynos so it’s impossible for Heroku to provide an IP address instead it provides a DNS target. Unfortunately GoDaddy doesn’t support ALIAS/ANAME records. You might want to check out other DNS providers who support ALIAS/ANAME out of the box to configure the APEX domain.